# Composer update failure

Tags: 8, composer

I am trying to update a site to Drupal 8.7 and getting a weird set of errors.  Can someone point me to how to best diagnose and fix the problem?

Here are the steps that I am taking:

1. When I try to update Drupal I use: `composer update drupal/core webflo/drupal-core-require-dev --with-all-dependencies`

   This results in

   ```
   > DrupalProject\composer\ScriptHandler::checkComposerVersion
   Loading composer repositories with package information
   Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
   Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

     Problem 1
       - drush/drush 9.6.2 requires chi-teck/drupal-code-generator ^1.28.1 -> satisfiable by chi-teck/drupal-code-generator[1.x-dev].
       - drush/drush 9.6.2 requires chi-teck/drupal-code-generator ^1.28.1 -> satisfiable by chi-teck/drupal-code-generator[1.x-dev].
       - drush/drush 9.6.2 requires chi-teck/drupal-code-generator ^1.28.1 -> satisfiable by chi-teck/drupal-code-generator[1.x-dev].
       - Conclusion: don't install chi-teck/drupal-code-generator 1.x-dev
       - Installation request for drush/drush (locked at 9.6.2, required as ^9.0.0) -> satisfiable by drush/drush[9.6.2].
   ```
2. results of `composer why-not drupal/core 8.7.0`:

   webflo/drupal-core-require-dev  8.6.15  requires  drupal/core (8.6.15)
   drupal/core                     8.7.0   requires  egulias/email-validator (^2.0)
   drupal-composer/drupal-project  -       requires  egulias/email-validator (^1.0)
3. Contents of composer.json:

   ```json
   {
       "name": "drupal-composer/drupal-project",
       "description": "Project template for Drupal 8 projects with composer",
       "type": "project",
       "license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
       "authors": [
           {
               "name": "",
               "role": ""
           }
       ],
       "repositories": [
           {
               "type": "composer",
               "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
           }
       ],
       "require": {
           "chi-teck/drupal-code-generator": "dev-master",
           "composer/installers": "^1.2",
           "cweagans/composer-patches": "^1.6.5",
           "drupal-composer/drupal-scaffold": "^2.5",
           "drupal/admin_toolbar": "^1.25",
           "drupal/chosen": "^2.6",
           "drupal/ckeditor_a11ychecker": "^1.0",
           "drupal/ckeditor_balloonpanel": "^1.1",
           "drupal/ckeditor_div_manager": "^1.0",
           "drupal/ckeditor_liststyle": "^1.3",
           "drupal/ckeditor_uploadimage": "^1.7",
           "drupal/console": "^1.0.2",
           "drupal/core": "^8.6",
           "drupal/devel": "^2.0",
           "drupal/entity_reference_integrity": "^1.0@RC",
           "drupal/eva": "^1.3",
           "drupal/imce": "^1.7",
           "drupal/inline_entity_form": "^1.0@RC",
           "drupal/ldap": "^3.0@beta",
           "drupal/markup": "^1.0@beta",
           "drupal/masquerade": "^2.0@beta",
           "drupal/migrate_plus": "^4.1",
           "drupal/migrate_source_csv": "^2.2",
           "drupal/migrate_tools": "^4.1",
           "drupal/module_filter": "^3.1",
           "drupal/readonly_field_widget": "^1.2",
           "drupal/serial": "1.x-dev",
           "drupal/taxonomy_access_fix": "^2.6",
           "drupal/token": "^1.5",
           "drupal/uuid_extra": "1.x-dev",
           "drush/drush": "^9.0.0",
           "egulias/email-validator": "^1.0",
           "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^2.4",
           "webflo/drupal-core-require-dev": "^8.6",
           "webflo/drupal-finder": "^1.0.0",
           "webmozart/path-util": "^2.3"
       },
       "require-dev": {
       },
       "conflict": {
           "drupal/drupal": "*"
       },
       "minimum-stability": "dev",
       "prefer-stable": true,
       "config": {
           "sort-packages": true
       },
       "autoload": {
           "classmap": [
               "scripts/composer/ScriptHandler.php"
           ],
           "files": ["load.environment.php"]
       },
       "scripts": {
           "pre-install-cmd": [
               "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::checkComposerVersion"
           ],
           "pre-update-cmd": [
               "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::checkComposerVersion"
           ],
           "post-install-cmd": [
               "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::createRequiredFiles"
           ],
           "post-update-cmd": [
               "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::createRequiredFiles"
           ]
       },
       "extra": {
           "patchLevel": {
               "drupal/core": "-p2"
           },
           "installer-paths": {
               "web/core": ["type:drupal-core"],
               "web/libraries/{$name}": ["type:drupal-library"],
               "web/modules/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-module"],
               "web/profiles/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-profile"],
               "web/themes/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-theme"],
               "drush/Commands/{$name}": ["type:drupal-drush"]
           },
           "drupal-scaffold": {
               "initial": {
                   ".editorconfig": "../.editorconfig",
                   ".gitattributes": "../.gitattributes"
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```
4. Results from `composer outdated`:

   ```
   alchemy/zippy                      0.4.3              0.4.9
   chi-teck/drupal-code-generator     dev-master 8209866 dev-master 4960fe0
   dflydev/dot-access-data            v1.1.0             v2.0.0
   drupal/core                        8.6.15             8.7.0
   egulias/email-validator            1.2.15             2.1.7
   league/container                   2.4.1              3.2.2
   paragonie/random_compat            v2.0.18            v9.99.99
   phar-io/manifest                   1.0.1              1.0.3
   phar-io/version                    1.0.1              2.0.1
   phpdocumentor/type-resolver        0.4.0              0.7.1
   phpunit/php-code-coverage          5.3.2              7.0.3
   phpunit/php-file-iterator          1.4.5              2.0.2
   phpunit/php-timer                  1.0.9              2.1.1
   phpunit/php-token-stream           2.0.2              3.0.1
   phpunit/phpunit                    6.5.14             8.1.3              
   phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects       5.0.10             6.1.2              Package phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
   ralouphie/getallheaders            2.0.5              3.0.3
   sebastian/comparator               2.1.3              3.0.2
   sebastian/diff                     2.0.1              3.0.2
   sebastian/environment              3.1.0              4.2.1
   sebastian/global-state             2.0.0              3.0.0
   sebastian/resource-operations      1.0.0              2.0.1
   stecman/symfony-console-completion 0.9.0              0.10.0
   symfony-cmf/routing                1.4.1              2.1.0
   symfony/config                     v3.4.27            v4.2.8
   symfony/console                    v3.4.27            v4.2.8
   symfony/css-selector               v3.4.27            v4.2.8
   symfony/debug                      v3.4.27            v4.2.8
   symfony/dependency-injection       v3.4.27            v4.2.8
   symfony/dom-crawler                v3.4.27            v4.2.8
   symfony/event-dispatcher           v3.4.27            v4.2.8
   symfony/filesystem                 v3.4.27            v4.2.8
   symfony/finder                     v3.4.27            v4.2.8
   symfony/http-foundation            v3.4.27            v4.2.8
   symfony/http-kernel                v3.4.27            v4.2.8
   symfony/phpunit-bridge             v3.4.27            v4.2.8
   symfony/process                    v3.4.27            v4.2.8
   symfony/routing                    v3.4.27            v4.2.8
   symfony/serializer                 v3.4.27            v4.2.8
   symfony/translation                v3.4.27            v4.2.8
   symfony/validator                  v3.4.27            v4.2.8
   symfony/yaml                       v3.4.27            v4.2.8
   twig/twig                          v1.40.1            v2.9.0
   typo3/phar-stream-wrapper          v2.1.0             v3.1.0
   vlucas/phpdotenv                   v2.5.2             v3.3.3
   webflo/drupal-core-require-dev     8.6.15             8.7.0
   zendframework/zend-diactoros       1.8.6              2.1.2
   ```

Per suggestion from @fgrep, I removed composer.lock and vendor/.  The result was even more errors:  (see [File linked as question was getting too long](https://lib.msu.edu/sites/default/files/results_from_composer_update_after_delete_lock_and_vendor.txt))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that the composer.json had a requirement for  `"egulias/email-validator": "^1.0"` and 8.7 requires 2.0.  I could not find any reason why 1.0 was in the requirements.  When I removed that requirement, the update proceeded without any problem.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by deleting composer.lock and vendor:

```
rm -Rf composer.lock vendor/
```

Then I ran a composer update:

```
composer update
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, but that did not work.  I will edit my question to add in the results of that command.